# Positioning options menu directly under highlighted text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show the user a pop up menu with some options if they highlight any text in the browser. I want the menu to be displayed directly under the highlighted text.

I am currently using `getBoundingClientRect()` on the `range` of the text. Passing the object to the menu and using the coordinates to set the positioning.

```
function doSomethingWithSelectedText() {
    let selectedText = getSelectedText();
    let sel;
    if (selectedText && selectedText.indexOf(' ') === -1) {
        console.log('SELECTED TEXT =>', selectedText)
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            let coords = range.getBoundingClientRect()
            setTimeout(() => { handleShowMenu(coords) }, 800)
        }

    }
}
```

```
const handleShowMenu = (coords) => {

    menu.style.display = 'block'
    menu.style.left = coords.x + 'px'
    menu.style.top = coords.y + 'px'
}
```

During some highlighting tests of various text elements I notice:

- The menu is positioned right under the `<p>` tags perfectly as to my desire.
- The menu is positioned under the `<h3>` but closer to the top, almost overlapping the text.
- The menu is positioned right under the `<h1>` but now partially overlapping the bottom of the text.

Any reason for this behavior, as well as a possible solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
menu.style.top = coords.y + 'px'
```

to

```
menu.style.top = coords.bottom + "px";
```

Should work if I am understanding your question correctly. You can use single quotes obviously if you prefer, I just prefer double quotes, and I would recommend adding in the semicolons you aren't including but again up to you on that I suppose.